# Trying to bring back results from IDs not containing a value

Tags: sql, filtering

I'm working with a dataset where one ID can have multiple sub IDs attached to them. what I'm trying to do is use a query to bring back IDs that DOES NOT CONTAIN a specific sub ID

Here's a sample table:

```
ID       SubID
1986782  1058
1986782  26579
1986782  145789
1986777  1058
1986777  26579
1986777  7893
```

The query I've got so far:

```
Select k.ID, k.SubID
From IDTable AS k
Where k.SubID != 145789
```

The result I want would be just

```
ID
1986777
```

because in its tables it does not have an entry for 145789 linked to its ID

what I've been getting though is both of them, and it just skips the one instance of 1986782

So how do I make it so that if 145789 comes up it omits that ID completely?

Comment: Put the sample data in proper columns, and it will be so much easier for us.

Comment: Thanks jarlh, sorry always had trouble trying to post here :(

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by ID` and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select ID
from IDTable 
group by ID
having sum(case when SubID = 145789 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ozCZpH24fpXy98VtGxciDu/0).
Results:

```
| ID      |
| ------- |
| 1986777 |
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, I managed to incorporate your query into my main query and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT IN` to filter out any matching `ID`s that have a `SubID` of 145789:

```
SELECT  ID
  FROM  IDTable
  WHERE ID NOT IN (
                  SELECT  ID
                    FROM  IDTable
                    WHERE SubID = 145789)
  GROUP BY ID
```

The sub-query fetches any `ID`s that have the `SubID` you *don't want*.  Then it gets all results that *do not* match those `ID`s.

I've added `GROUP BY ID` so that you get distinct `ID`s only (rather than multiple rows for each `ID` and `SubID`), which is what I think you wanted.

Comment: Why not do `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct result?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I tried it on the data set that I had for the company I work for, unfortunately it seems that but when I try to limit it to a certain subset of IDs, it takes a long time for it to give its results.   I can run it, but it only runs smoothly if I set it to look at everything as opposed to a set of IDs for a specific department... if that makes sense

Comment: @jarlh: would select distinct be more optimized vs group by? I try to keep my queries optimized so I don't use too much system resources and slow down or systems

Comment: @MasatoIndou, trust the optimizer here! Write readable code, much easier to maintain.